# when to include ; at the end of while loop in java

Tags: java, while-loop

We are currently learning the complexity of algorithms and one of them we have to analysis is quicksort,

I went online to find an working quicksort code to do the analysis and noticed something

```
int partition(int arr[], int left, int right)
{
  int i = left, j = right;
  int tmp;
  int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

  while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
              i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
              j--;
        if (i <= j) {
              tmp = arr[i];
              arr[i] = arr[j];
              arr[j] = tmp;
              i++;
              j--;
        }
  };

  return i;
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
      int index = partition(arr, left, right);
      if (left < index - 1)
            quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
      if (index < right)
            quickSort(arr, index, right);
}
```

I noticed there is a `;` at the end of the while loop in the partition function. The code seems to be working fine with it, but if I remove it, it still compiles and runs but it doesn't work correctly, so it intrigued me: when should there be a `;` in the end of a while loop?

Comment: Now try adding as many `;` as you'd like `...};;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`.

Comment: Which `;` are you referring to? Note that there are three while loops in here (two of which are written in nasty, error-prone no-braces syntax that if you're just learning Java, you should avoid at all costs...).

Comment: It's merely an empty statement following the while block. The author probably typed it in out of habit and since it's not a syntax error, it was just left there.

Comment: Hard to believe it doesn't work the same with or without. Unless the `while` statement is part of an outer brace-less compound statement the extra ; does nothing. It's just the null statement. But there are other errors here: I doubt that the code works correctly at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo.  It doesn't actively *harm* the code, as the block statement is unaffected by the placement of that semicolon, but it certainly doesn't help readability.

IntelliJ or any other IDE will report this in their inspections as "unnecessary semicolon" or "superfluous", or something to that effect.

In general, you want to *avoid* confusing syntax like that.  Despite it being valid syntax, its placement is actively confusing.

Comment: @kolonel That doesn't imply that it can't be a typo.

Comment: @EJP what is your definition of a typo? if we can't agree on that, then we can't learn from this. My definition of a typo is that it violates the syntax of the language (including not using proper semantics ofcourse).

Comment: @EJP this does not violate the syntax of the language, it doesn't. If I am wrong then clearly tell me why, but by going to the first principle of the language.

Comment: @kolonel No. A typo is an unintentional typing error, and it has been since Gutenberg. In this case it is also legal syntax. I haven't disputed that any time. What I am disputing here is your logic. There is a false inference. The fact that it is legal syntax doesn't mean that it can't also be a typo.

Comment: Just because it doesn't violate the syntax or grammar rules of a language, that doesn't necessarily make it right, or in this case, *appropriate*.

Comment: @kolonel Please stop this. The relevant part of the JLS is [Chapter 18](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html). You cited it yourself. The extra `;` is a null statement. OK? Or are you claiming that this answer is factually incorrect? You seem to be arguing about nothing.

Comment: @kolonel Now you're misquoting. The answer doesn't say 'you can't do this' at all. On the contrary, it specifically says 'in general, you want to avoid confusing syntax like that.' This doesn't appear to me to be any different from 'one should not do this even though you can'.

Comment: @Makoto thanks for the clarification. I just usually prefer answers that go back to the first principle. It is important for better learning.

Comment: @EJP thanks for the clarification. I just usually prefer answers that go back to the first principle. It is important for better learning.

Comment: @kolonel I haven't clarified anything except what the answer already says, or what you said yourself. It all seems completely unnecessary to me. And citing chapter and verse of trivia like this really isn't always necessary either. All you've done here is argue about nothing, with false inferences and misattributions. It's not constructive and I have flagged it accordingly. You would have been better employed clarifying your own answer as requested.

Comment: @EJP do what you need to do, but the clarification is that you explained what you mean by typo.

Comment: @kolonel There you go again. It isn't what *I* mean by 'typo'. It's *what the word means.* 'Typographical error'. It's been used for hundreds of years. Nothing to do with 'syntax error' whatsoever. As everywhere else in this discussion, you're using straw-man arguments.